# How to inherit permissions on DRF for class based views?

Tags: python, django, model-view-controller, permissions

```
class ViewTwo(APIView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsBar,)

class ViewThree(ViewTwo):
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsXYZ,)
```

How can `ViewThree` inherit `ViewTwo` permissions in order to have both `permissions.IsBar` and `permissions.IsXYZ` permission classes?

Comment: Are you using **Django REST Framework**?

Comment: no, plain Django

Comment: Do the permissions currently working?

Comment: @JPG, actually not, sorry. It inherits from `ApiView` lemme correct that. I'm wondering if there is a way to do that also for plain Django class based views.

Comment: lemme update this question to attend to both frameworks. It's confusing now

Comment: now it seems ambiguous. Pls add more details like, how do you want to implement the inheriting.

Comment: I left just for the DRF case which was my first question. Adding multiple cases for different frameworks made the question indeed very confusing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose, you need to implement `get_permissions` method in `ViewThree` which instantiates and returns the list of permissions that this view requires:

```
class ViewThree(ViewTwo):
    def get_permissions(self):
        return super().get_permissions() + (permissions.IsXYZ,)
```

Comment: In which version this is available? couldn't find any mentions on the docs. Can you put a link to that?

Comment: @JulioMarins Check [this](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/views/#get_permissionsself).

Comment: @Lev Zakharov The original post didn't mention about DRF.  Apart from that, the **`TemplateView`** class is ***not part of the DRF***

Comment: @JPG and `permission_classes` not a part of Django views:) Moreover `permissions` module also usually refers to DRF not to Django.

Answer (score 0):

Simply define the permissions on ViewThree by appending those from ViewTwo.

```
class ViewTwo(TemplateView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsBar,)

class ViewThree(ViewTwo):
    permission_classes = ViewTwo.permission_classes + (permissions.IsXYZ,)
```

Comment: I'm not sure that this is a good solution, because permissions in `ViewThree` are not really connected with the parent class, but they're connected with hardcoded `ViewTwo.permission_classes`.

Comment: It is not really hardcoding. Check this example for inheriting Meta class. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/models/#meta-inheritance.

Comment: I could be wrong though. I just found the two examples pretty similar where we have to mention the parent more than once.

Comment: I just found this one as well  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13404476/inherited-class-variable-modification-in-python